# Database Migration (MSSQL->MySQL) using Talend's Dynamic Schema

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, database-migration, talend

I just recently tried using Talend Cloud Data Integration (Talend Studio 7.2)

and I'm figuring how to dynamically migrate a whole MSSQL server database to MySQL(blank DB).

So far, I heard that it's possible to do that with Talent's Dynamic Schema.

However, I only found a [tutorial for a table (data) migration](https://www.talend.com/blog/2019/11/11/migrate-data-between-databases-one-job-using-dynamic-schema/?_ga=2.210703573.17725181.1583113852-1421166428.1582596976), or some post that didn't specifically explained much about settings and components to use.

Here's my job design

I'm using global variable to dynamically define the table, however, I'm not sure how i can define the schema dynamically.
** I have about 100 tables in each databases(MSSQL) and they all have different number and types of columns which is not applicable to the tutorial written [here](https://www.talend.com/blog/2019/11/11/migrate-data-between-databases-one-job-using-dynamic-schema/?_ga=2.210703573.17725181.1583113852-1421166428.1582596976).

Can you let me know how I can define my schema dynamically?

[image: DBInput]
[image: DBOutput]

I am hoping to find a solution where one job could perform a whole database migration. Eg) Iterating tables in a source DB then generate an output a destination DB.

Please let me know either if I should proceed with Dynamic Schema or Job Template + job design/components/setting needed.

Thank you